# I have changed my old website from asp.net to php and i need to redirect the pages using web.config

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

This is my current web.config file where i am trying to redirect the page of www.abadbuilders.com/projects/spice-town to www.abadbuilders.com/project. But what happens actually is that it doesn't redirect to the particular page instead it gets an 404 page not found error. Can anyone helps me on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

web.config is the configuration file for ASP.net it wont work with PHP.

If you are using an Apache server for your website then you can `.htaccess` file to set the URL redirection, else you can code in the PHP code itself using `header('redirect', 'http://the.url/you/wish/');`

For your reference

[httpd URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

[PHP: Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: I am using a windows server. So in-order to remove index  (in codeigniter) i have to use a web.config file. So i need a code redirect old website pages to new one.

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting in CodeIgniter you can use Routes configuration.

You need to edit the file `application/config/routes.php`

You need to add after this line of code

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Your rewrite code will be like this

```
$route['projects/(:any)'] = 'project';
```

I hope you have a controller `Project` that have functions to display projects.

Comment: Thank you.. Even its not the exact answer i am looking for i can adjust with it.